# Update Facebook mini-site how to ask link for new bug tracking tool

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

On this [page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (open in incognito tab), can you update the link for reporting bugs to the [new Facebook bug tracker tool](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs) that they [announced today](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/559/)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Stack Overflow Facebook mini-site hasn't existed for years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I updated this site setting with the new URL.